# Split String Array with the split condtioner

Tags: java, arrays, split

Assume i want to split,

```
String line = "ABCDEFG";
```

Into,

```
{"ABCD","EFG"}
```

I would do this,

```
String[] alpha = line.split('D');
```

But is gives me,

```
{"ABC","EFG"}
```

Notice that the 'D' is missing, how do i split it while keeping the character?

Comment: It's with a look-ahead. I think `String[] alpha = line.split("(?=D)");` should work.

Comment: You can also create an arrayList and split after every four characters

Comment: Im actually splitting the user inputs so i dont know what the input will be so can do that

Comment: @AntonH i get, Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
?=

Comment: @CharinduEdirisooriya You May need to check your includes, because it works (albeit with `E` instead of `D`) : https://www.ideone.com/yiY613

Comment: but what is the criteria? split in 4 chars groups?

Comment: @CharinduEdirisooriya There's probably something else in your regex causing that actual message. Could you provide the actual regex you're trying to get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a function to do what you want.

```
public static String[] splitWise(String line,char a){
    String[] res= {"",""};
    Boolean added=false;
    for(int i=0;i<line.length()-1;i++)
    {
        if(line.charAt(i)==a)
        {
            //change next line if you want the element you split in the second element of the array
            res[0]+= line.charAt(i);
            added=true;
        }else if(!added){
            res[0] += line.charAt(i);

        }else
            res[1] += line.charAt(i);

    }
    return res;
}
```

I think it's what you want. You just need to call the function like this:

```
String[] alpha = splitWise(line,'D');
```

Comment: I figured my way around it by adding a special character in front of the chartater i want to split from, and then i split it from the special character. This answer also seems to work!